# Why does while not work with an if statement and else

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm looking to print the collatz sequensce and i want the sequence to stop at 1.

why does this result in an infinite loop and the `while` part of the code does not work;

```
number = input('Enter a no')
number = int(number)
while number !=1:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number= number//2
        print(number)

    if number % 2 != 0:
        number=  3 * number + 1
        print(number)
```

but this works;

```
number = input('Enter a no')
number = int(number)
while number !=1:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number= number//2
        print(number)

    else:
        number=  3 * number + 1
        print(number)
```

Why does the `while` not work if i have two `if` satements ?
It works if i use an `elif` or `else` statement at the end. but not when i have two `if`

Comment: could you please elaborate ? i do not understand

Comment: Walk through your problem with an input of `0` (it will end up in an infinite loop for both of your loops)

Comment: could you tell me about the `while` and `if` loop interaction?

Comment: Nothing fancy is happening. Your logic does exactly how its written. You do know the different between an `if` and and `else` right?

Comment: i do but if there are two `if` and only one of them will be true, a number must be odd or even. both are working as expected. i do not understand why the while is not coming into play if there are two `if`

Comment: The logic of two ifs is not the same logic of an if else unless you have a `continue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the first version doesn't work is because you are *potentially* modifying `number` twice in the loop.

With the `else` you test `number % 2` — if there is no remainder you change `number` by dividing it by two, then the *else* is skipped and you test number `!=` 1 and loop again. If there *is* a remainder you skip that and perform the else, setting `number = 3 * number + 1` and you test number `!=` 1 to loop again. In either case you have changed "number" in only *one* of the two possible ways.

With the two *ifs* you test `number % 2` — if there is no remainder you change `number` by dividing it by two, then you test `number % 2` *again* ... but `number` ***could have changed*** before you test it the second time.

Imagine running this with number starting at `6`
6 divided by 2 is 3 with 0 remainder, so `6 % 2 == 0` and you execute `number = number//2` which gives `3`
**Now** you test `if number % 2 != 0` … but number *now* is already 3, and 3 divided by 2 is 1 with a remainder of 1 — that is, `3 % 2 == 1` so that `number % 2` is indeed `!= 0`, so now you change number *again*, for the second time in the loop.

With the `else` there is *no way* you will ever change number twice in one iteration of the loop; with the two 'if's you can divide by 2 *and then also* multiply and add.